# R using complete function for percent cover database

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

I am attempting to populate implicitly missing data in a percent cover database.  For each Site, Transect, and Quadrat I want all "Labels" from the entire database included for each Quadrat.  As such, any Label that is missing from a specific quadrat should be included with "percent_cover" variable equal to 0 (see desired output).

#### Database

```
data <- structure(list(Site = c("HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", 
"HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", 
"HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN"), Transect = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Quadrat = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Label = c("Bare-Subst", 
"CCA", "PorComp", "PorLob", "Turf", "Urchins", "Bare-Subst", 
"CCA", "PocMea", "PorComp", "PorLob", "Turf", "Bare-Subst", "CCA", 
"MontiPat", "PocMea", "PorComp", "PorLob", "Turf"), percent_cover = c(0.15, 
0.07, 0.18, 0.42, 0.17, 0.01, 0.06, 0.04, 0.01, 0.09, 0.55, 0.25, 
0.05, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.24, 0.37, 0.28)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -19L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Transect = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Quadrat = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Aux4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), Aux5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), Row = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Column = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Label = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), groups = structure(list(
    Site = c("HAN", "HAN", "HAN"), Transect = c(1, 1, 1), Quadrat = c(1, 
    2, 3), .rows = list(1:6, 7:12, 13:19)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

#### Desired Database

```
data_desired <- structure(list(Site = c("HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", 
"HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", 
"HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN"
), Transect = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Quadrat = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2), Label = c("Bare-Subst", 
"CCA", "MontiPat", "PocMea", "PorComp", "PorLob", "Turf", "Urchins", 
"Bare-Subst", "CCA", "MontiPat", "PocMea", "PorComp", "PorLob", 
"Turf", "Urchins", "Bare-Subst", "CCA", "MontiPat", "PocMea", 
"PorComp", "PorLob", "Turf", "Urchins"), percent_cover = c(0.15, 
0.07, 0, 0, 0.18, 0.42, 0.17, 0.01, 0.06, 0.04, 0, 0.01, 0.09, 
0.55, 0.25, 0, 0.05, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.24, 0.37, 0.28, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Transect = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Quadrat = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Label = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), percent_cover = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

I attempted to do this using the complete() function.  However, this function as written returns the input database with no changes:

#### Attempted solution

```
data_new <- data %>% complete(Site, Transect, Quadrat, Label, fill = list(percent_cover = 0))
```

I would like to alter my code here to obtain the desired output using the complete function or other suggested functions (I prefer using complete).  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`complete` by default is honoring your groups, so technically within each group everything is being `complete`d just fine.

Ungroup, then try again:

```r
ungroup(data) %>%
  complete(Site, Transect, Quadrat, Label, fill = list(percent_cover = 0))
# # A tibble: 24 x 5
#    Site  Transect Quadrat Label      percent_cover
#    <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
#  1 HAN          1       1 Bare-Subst          0.15
#  2 HAN          1       1 CCA                 0.07
#  3 HAN          1       1 MontiPat            0   
#  4 HAN          1       1 PocMea              0   
#  5 HAN          1       1 PorComp             0.18
#  6 HAN          1       1 PorLob              0.42
#  7 HAN          1       1 Turf                0.17
#  8 HAN          1       1 Urchins             0.01
#  9 HAN          1       2 Bare-Subst          0.06
# 10 HAN          1       2 CCA                 0.04
# # ... with 14 more rows
```

Comment: This solved my issue.  Thank you!